# How to get hardware information with Python

Tags: python, memory, module, get, hardware

I'm trying to retrieve hardware information with Python. Indeed, I want to get the total memory RAM of a computer. I've already tried to use "platform" and "sys" modules, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: The amount of RAM in use at that moment, or the total amount of RAM available?

Comment: The total amount of RAM available ;)

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the standard library, short of writing a far-too-long script with `ctypes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.virtual_memory()
vmem(total=8374149120L, available=2081050624L, percent=75.1, used=8074080256L, free=300068864L, active=3294920704, inactive=1361616896, buffers=529895424L, cached=1251086336)
>>> psutil.swap_memory()
swap(total=2097147904L, used=296128512L, free=1801019392L, percent=14.1, sin=304193536, sout=677842944)
>>>
```